# NEXUS RM3 - how to filter specific repositories for role/privileges

Tags: nexus, nexus3

How can I give permission to users just to view specific repos? so it save a lot of time if it is possible to create a privilege to filter with these criteria:

- All type of repos start with prefix `test`

What I've tried:

Using wildcard to create privilege `nexus:repository-view:*:test*:browse`
to filter all repositories which starts with prefix `test`

This can save a lot of time for adding repos one by one to each specific role.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. You can target all repos, all repos of a certain format (maven, apt, yum....). a specific repository, a certain path inside a set of repositories (content selector)--- but you can't target a list of repos based on a name prefix. Meanwhile, you could use the api to get the list you need and add them to a specific role automatically from a script you can run on a regular basis (or manually).

Comment: Thanks, yes at the end, used API to get all list and using Terraform to manage them. (using Terraform helped as it is stateful)